# How can my android device pass a file to a windows 8 pc?

Tags: android, wifi

I am currently designing an android campus voting system. My problem is how can I pass a vote from the device to the laptop as server using Wi-Fi?

I mean, what exactly is the file type my device would generate if i try to vote(or can I decide what file type to use? If so, what is the fastest and most resourceful file type)?

I've been reading and trying to make my laptop into a Wi-Fi hotspot and successfully connected, but, no sharing happened.

I haven't done creating the View/GUI but I was just wondering how will my device pass the vote that the end-user will cast.

I decided to use a Wi-Fi to somewhat prevent non-students from voting, but all suggestions (just in layman's term please, I'm a newbie, I am still studying android programming) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is simple, do not look at it like it is something huge just because it involves different operating system, basically you need to have some simple `php` skills, then follow this to tutorial its great I used it to, I once has a big problem like you but after reading this [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial I had all the knowledge needed to use my phone with a php server, after you are done with this you can use a tool like `ngrok` to make your pc a virtual server, ngrok generates a link for your local machine so you can use that link to link your app and the server on your pc, or you can look at how to make a local connection between your phone and pc without any use of `ngrok`

Comment: your link is great. But I failed to tell you I am using SQL Server. I tried in the past to install xammp and sql server management studio and they were conflicting in port 8 (or something) not to mention phpmyadmin doesn't support stored procedures.

Comment: the port issue is something easy, if you have `VMARE` or any virtual machine chances are it is using it, which ever is installed first takes up the port

Comment: so it was the vmware, not the xamp/wamp?

Comment: vmare uses the same ports as xamp, you need xamp to make a virtual server, so change the port to be used by vmare or better still change port to be used by xamp then u will have both running side by side

Answer (score 0):

Probably HTTPS to a PHP script on a web server (or a SSL link to a vote server) would work, but you definitely want to think about how to verify that the voter is a current student, not trying to pretend to be another student, etc.  WiFi access alone is probably not enough to authenticate the voter.  Unless your vote is a lot more complicated than I expect, verifying the identity of the voter is the greater problem.  So I would recommend putting a lot of thought into how to authenticate your voters, especially in the case of someone trying to "buy" an election.

Be Paranoid - They ARE out to get you!

Comment: Registration will be held in campus's computer stations not via online, and will produce one-time-passcode for the voter to use. it will be up for the election officers how to keep a non student from registering or a current student from registering more than once.